# Nodejs axios.get error when sending HTTPS get request

Tags: node.js, axios, http-get

I am using the Axios version `0.21.1`.
I am sending HTTPS get request as below.

When I run below code, the #2 line inside the try block `console.log...` throws error.
But the error object I get in `catch` is empty. Not sure why log is throwing error.

```
try {
    let getRes = await axios.get(myUrl, {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}});
    console.log("getRes: " + JSON.stringify(getRes));
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

If I run the following version with #2 parameter as `{}` or `null` for `axios.get`.
I get the error printed in `catch` but I am not sure why it is failing.

```
try {
    let getRes = await axios.get(myUrl, {}, {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}});
    console.log("getRes: " + JSON.stringify(getRes));
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

The error I get is `401 Unauthorized`.
From the Postman, this URL is working fine with the same `Bearer` token as I am using from the code.

I have even tried the below code, with the behavior same as #1 case:

```
let getrRes = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: myUrl,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+token
    }
});
```

I don't want to have request body for this get request.
What can be the issue and how to call `axios.get` correctly?

Comment: Can you show the error the `console.log` throws? The error might be caused be `JSON.stringify` so try simple `console.log(getRes)`

Comment: If I do console.log then I get `[object object]`. for the case #2.  As per the documentation the #2 param for the `axios.get` is params not sure what to provide when params are empty.

Comment: Even I am not able to print the value return by the `axios.get` the `JSON.parse` just crashes when trying to parse. I did try all the combination for the get request but still it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first program is the right one! But inside it's your console.log() that is not good: you cannot use the `JSON.stringify()` method on the `getRes` object returned by `axios`, that's why your program goes into the catch.

To display the response, either don't use `JSON.stringify()`, or use `JSON.stringify()` on the data returned by axios (which is getRes.data)

```
try {
    let getRes = await axios.get(myUrl, {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}});
    console.log("getRes: " + JSON.stringify(getRes.data));
    // OR
    console.log("getRes: " + getRes);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
}
```

Note that you can't use the `JSON.stringify()` on the error that you got in the catch either! That's why you only had an empty object.

Comment: I did figure out the issue. Axios doc did not mention this anywhere. Yes, converting response to JSON was causing this issue. I wonder why so, what is inside response that cannot be parsed at the end it JS object I guess?

Comment: @User7723337 It might be caused by "Circular reference" for example the response could have a property which is reference to itself like if you did `getRes.res = getRes;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the exact cause of error, change the `console.log` in your try catch block. Don't try to `JSON.strigify` the error, rather just dump it onto the console. This will make sure to dump the error **as-is**, onto the console.

```js
try {
  let getRes = await axios.get(myUrl, {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}});
  console.log("getRes: " + JSON.stringify(getRes));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

If you still wish to get a fine grained error message, you can convert the error into string by using one of the following statements inside your catch clause:

```js
console.log(error.message);
console.log(error.toString());
```